# Not able to fetch data inside node-cron schedule method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

so I was trying to schedule an update in the database every night at 12, and I am able to run Cron jobs using my server, but I am not able to fetch data using Axios, I tried an external URL from a tutorial like "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" and the data comes, but when I use the url/routes I made to fetch data in the reactjs front end.. like this "http://localhost:9000/api/getAllDealHeader" and pass it as URL, it gives an error like

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:183:27) {
errno: 'ECONNRESET',
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read',
config: {
url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/getAllDealHeader',
method: 'get',
headers: {
  Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'User-Agent': 'axios/0.20.0'
},
transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
timeout: 0,
adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
maxContentLength: -1,
maxBodyLength: -1,
validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
data: undefined
 },
 request: Writable {
_writableState: WritableState {
  objectMode: false,
  highWaterMark: 16384,
  finalCalled: false,
  needDrain: false,
  ending: false,
  ended: false,
  finished: false,
  destroyed: false,
  decodeStrings: true,
  defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
  length: 0,
  writing: false,
  corked: 0,
  sync: true,
  bufferProcessing: false,
  onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
  writecb: null,
  writelen: 0,
  bufferedRequest: null,
  lastBufferedRequest: null,
  pendingcb: 0,
  prefinished: false,
  errorEmitted: false,
  emitClose: true,
  autoDestroy: false,
  bufferedRequestCount: 0,
  corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
},
writable: true,
_events: [Object: null prototype] {
  response: [Function: handleResponse],
  error: [Function: handleRequestError]
},
_eventsCount: 2,
_maxListeners: undefined,
_options: {
  maxRedirects: 21,
  maxBodyLength: 10485760,
  protocol: 'http:',
  path: '/api/getAllDealHeader',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: [Object],
  agent: undefined,
  agents: [Object],
  auth: undefined,
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '9000',
  nativeProtocols: [Object],
  pathname: '/api/getAllDealHeader'
},
_ended: true,
_ending: true,
_redirectCount: 0,
_redirects: [],
_requestBodyLength: 0,
_requestBodyBuffers: [],
_onNativeResponse: [Function],
_currentRequest: ClientRequest {
  _events: [Object: null prototype],
  _eventsCount: 7,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  _last: true,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 0,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket: [Socket],
  connection: [Socket],
  _header: 'GET /api/getAllDealHeader HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
    'User-Agent: axios/0.20.0\r\n' +
    'Host: localhost:9000\r\n' +
    'Connection: close\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
  agent: [Agent],
  socketPath: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api/getAllDealHeader',
  _ended: false,
  res: null,
  aborted: false,
  timeoutCb: null,
  upgradeOrConnect: false,
  parser: null,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  _redirectable: [Circular],
  [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
  [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object: null prototype]
  },
  _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/api/getAllDealHeader'
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
  timeoutCb: null,
  upgradeOrConnect: false,
  parser: null,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  _redirectable: [Circular],
  [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
  [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object: null prototype]
},
_currentUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/api/getAllDealHeader'
},
response: undefined,
isAxiosError: true,
toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

My code is

```
const getData = async url => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const data = response.data;
    console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
   }
};


cron.schedule("59 * * * * *", () => {
     console.log("running a task every half minute");

     let url = 'http://localhost:9000/api/getAllDealHeader'
     getData(url);

})
```

I'm using MySQL as my DB and sequelize as my ORM.
Can someone help me, where am I going wrong and what should I do..

Comment: Hello Asim, do you remember how you solved the case?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the variable name you are using in your function is incorrect it's lowercase but you are using uppercase in function.

```
     cron.schedule("59 * * * * *",async () => {
   console.log("running a task every half minute");

   let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
 await getData(url);
```

})

Comment: umm, my bad, but the name was correct in my code, that was not the issues..